# UnityContainer check dependency lifetimes consistency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is there any way in UnityContainer check lifetime consistency between type and its dependencies?

For example I want to know (as error or warning, etc) if type with `ControllerLifetimeManager` has dependency that have `TrancientLifetimeManager`.

In XML config it look like:

```xml
<register type="ITransient" mapTo="TransientType">
  <lifetime type="transient" />
</register>

<register type="ISingletone" mapTo="SingletoneType">
  <lifetime type="singletone" />
  <constructor>
    <param name="dependecyParam" dependencyType="ITransient" />
  </constructor>
</register>
```